# Regex for validating : Firstname LastName(e.g Ben Smith)

Tags: java, regex

```
String getname(){

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name;
    System.out.println("Enter your name:");
    name= input.next();

    String name_pattern = "^[A-Za-z]+(\\s[A-Za-z]+)$";//this regex isnt validating Ben Smith
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(name_pattern);
    Matcher regexmatcher = pattern.matcher(name);

    if(!regexmatcher.matches()){
        System.out.println("Name format not correct");
     }

    return name;

}
```

I also need to take the input again and again until the correct format is entered. How do i do that? My current regex prints "Name format not correct" when I input "Ben Smith" though it should not print that because Ben Smith is a valid input!

Comment: Somewhat related: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: Which language are you using here? That might be relevant.

Comment: @MaryamMasood Have you tried debugging it? Or at least print `name` between input and matching? As for ‘*again and again* […] *How do i do that?*’: Have you heard about loops?

Comment: little tip it's better to use `\w` instead `[a-zA-Z]`

Comment: Quote interpolation there?

Comment: Why are there parentheses in your test? You are not using them so remove them until you get it to work.

Comment: @Sobrique I am using java

Comment: OK. It's relevant because of handling of e.g. string quoting varies between languages.

Comment: @Biffen Can you please specify what do you exactly mean by double-escape? should i add two spaces before \\s? \s will not work as i am using java. I tried using while loop to take the input again but it didnt work

Comment: @MaryamMasood That comment was for @Aaron, who thought `\\s` was wrong. It is not; that part of your code is correct.

Comment: @Sobrique what is quote interpolation? :/

Comment: Some languages will process strings in double quotes in a different way to single quotes. E.g. `"\n"` in shell-style will be a linefeed, because it interpolates the `\n`. But in single quotes: `'\n'` it will treat it as a literal. So in your example - this is the difference between `\\s` and `\s`.

Answer (score 4):

`input.next` returns the next token from the input rather than the next line. You may set another delimiter in Scanner to return lines but the most custom way is to use

```
name= input.nextLine();
```

Comment: Maybe `input.next(pattern)` would be more appropriate? The pattern validation could be done by `input.hasNext(pattern)` then veryfing there is no more input with `!input.hasNext()` I guess.

Comment: here, how do we delimit a text (line by line) and what we expected to read (pattern) are quite unrelated things, and if we try to combine them in such a way, we will have to think what to do if we have anything else in the input and how to skip it in this case.

Comment: Should i add this in my while loop?

Comment: Yes, simply changing `next` to `nextLine`

Comment: Then mark the answer as correct and welcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

The Scanner's `next()` method returns only the next word, in your case "Ben". Replace that with `nextLine()` to get the whole name.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String name;
System.out.println("Enter your name:");
name = input.nextLine();
```

With that your regular expression matches "Ben Smith".

Answer (score -2):

`^[A-Za-z ]+$` is enough.

```
private final static Pattern NAME_VALIDATOR = Pattern.compile("^[A-Za-z ]+$");
[...]
System.out.println(NAME_VALIDATOR.matcher("Ben Smith").matches());
```

Note that the Pattern is always the same, so you can just create it once instead of creating it every time you enter the method.

Also note that this will not validate names with `'`, e.g. `O'Brian`, neither foreign names, e.g. `Mätthaus`. Consider using `\p{L}` instead.

---

As a comment points out:

> "As far as I understand they want only two words with a space
>   inbetween to be valid"

Then the regex would be `"^[A-Za-z]+ [A-Za-z]+$"` instead.

Comment: I don't think that does what OP wants, though. As far as I understand they want only two words with a space inbetween to be valid (which is a stupid requirement for a name, but that's another story).

Comment: That would also match "B e n S m i t h" though, which OP might not like

Comment: @m0skit0 The new regex is *very* close to OP's. Perhaps an explanation of the (minor) differences would be nice? Otherwise it's not much of an answer, if you ask me.

Comment: @m0skit0 "^[A-Za-z]+ [A-Za-z]+$" the regex still prints name format not correct on ben smith

Comment: @MaryamMasood Regex correctly matches `"Ben Smith" string`. Your problem is your input reading, not your regex. See AndreyS Scherbakov's answer.

Comment: @Biffen Yes, in fact the regex is basically the same, no need to explain. Actually her error was not on the regex but on how she was reading the string from input.

Comment: @m0skit0 Yes my bad, the regex was perfectly fine, i was making a mistake while taking the input, thanks for the help!